# Simple ASMX WebService and DLL not loaded

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, dll, asmx

I've a problem running an ASMX Web Service. I'm Calling a DLL from a method (AceptaTools.dll) and this DLL load ca4xml.dll.

AceptaTools.dll has been registered with REGSVR32. But ca4xml.dll Can't.

When i Invoke the service:

```
_objURL = _CA4XML.GetLastResponse();
```

i get a message "ca4xml.dll not loaded".

Looking al Dependency Walker:

Here both files in detail:
[image]

Both DLL are in BIN folder and my project run as x86... Why can't load?? Please help.

```
[WebMethod]

public string Send(string Ip, string Puerto, string NroDocumento, string TipoDocumento, string Comando, string Impresora, string Linea)
{
    try
    {
        int _Result = 0;
        string _Null = "";
        string _objURL;

        //Config Capsula
        string serverConfig = "cfg|" + Ip.ToString() + "|" + Puerto.ToString() + "|10";

        //Impresora FACTURA,1 por Defecto.
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Impresora)) { Impresora = "FACTURA,1"; }
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(NroDocumento)) { NroDocumento = "0"; }
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Comando)) { Comando = "generar"; }

        //Nuevo CAXML Cliente
        AceptaTools.CA4XML_Client _CA4XML = new CA4XML_Client();

        _Result = _CA4XML.Send(ref serverConfig, ref NroDocumento, ref Comando, ref Impresora, ref Linea, out _Null);


        if (_Result != 0)
        {
            _objURL = _CA4XML.GetLastResponse(); //Get URL
            return _objURL.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            return "Error";
        }


    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return ex.Message.ToString();
    }
}
```

}

[image]

Comment: It doesnt look like the ca4xml dll is referenced by your project at the moment

Comment: Thanks, I added the reference and both files are in BIN folder, but does not work

Comment: is ca4xml.dll a .NET assembly or is it a native assembly?

Comment: ca4xml.dll Isn't a NET assembly. I've tried to open it with .NET Reflector. Looks like a native dll.

Comment: FYI, `Exception.Message` is already a string, so you don't need .ToString().

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure that the `ca4xml.dll` is deployed properly? Since I guess it is not referenced as .NET assembly the VS will treat it like a normal file and you will need to specifically tell VS to include it when deploying.

Do the following steps to check whether deployment has been setup properly:

Open the Solution Explorer -> Got to the `ca4xml.dll` -> Right click -> Select `Properties` -> Set `Build Action = None` & `Copy to Output = Always`

Also in addition to the `Dependency Walker` I suggest to use `Process Monitor`. When you use the file access view (disregarding registry changes etc.) you can see all the locations where a process tries to load a dll from. Afterwards you can make sure that the dll you are missing is in one of the listed locations, here is the link:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645

Comment: I did it. Both files are in bin folder. But the message "ca4xml.dll not loaded" is still there

Comment: @IraDramarenko Which bin folder, the bin folder in the project or the deployment build folder?

Answer (score 0):

When you do not load DLL in the program because you need to update some things .
you can update project in nuget manager